# How to draw 3 in one comparison graph from three different files using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My intention is to plot three lines from three separate files. I am trying via the following code but the graph is vanishing within a splash. The labeling and title are not visible. I am sharing the code here, please help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1,y1= np.loadtxt('MaxMin1.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)

x1 = x1.astype(int)
y1 = y1.astype(float)

x2,y2= np.loadtxt('MaxMin2.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)

x2 = x2.astype(int)
y2 = y2.astype(float)

x3,y3= np.loadtxt('MaxMin3.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)

x3 = x3.astype(int)
y3 = y3.astype(float)

# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('<------Instances(count)------>') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/sq.sec)') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Fall Detection Comparison graph')

fig=plt.figure()
fig.show()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x1,y1,c='b',marker="^",ls='--',label='Normal',fillstyle='none')
ax.plot(x2,y2,c='g',marker=(8,2,0),ls='--',label='Recovery')
ax.plot(x3,y3,c='k',ls='-',label='No-Recovery')

plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Running Python 2.7.15 in Windows 10.

Comment: try `plt.show()` instead of `plt.draw()`

Comment: Thanks, It is working now.

Comment: However cannot add the labels.                                                                         'code' # naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('<------Instances(count)------>') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/sq.sec)') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Fall Detection Comparison graph')    is not working

Comment: That's because you are creating the labels *before* you create the figure and the axes

Comment: Got it, Thanks.